# Especificar caminho do Miktex no Rstudio

Tags: r

Estou tentando compilar um arquivo .Rmd para pdf usando o Knitr do Rstudio. Como estou usando um computador (Windows 7) com restrições de permissão, eu tive que instalar o MikTeX na pasta Documentos e o Rstudio não está encontrando essa instalação. Gostaria de saber se, no Rstudio, há uma maneira de especificar diretamente o caminho da instalação do MikTex.

Quando tento rodar o Knit PDF, a seguinte mensagem de erro é enviada:

```
No TeX installation detected (TeX is required to create PDF output).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que o Rstudio encontra a instalação sem problemas. No meu caso não estava funcionando porque eu instalei o *MikTeX basic*, e o Knitr exige a instalação da versão completa. Depois de instalar a versão completa, consegui compilar normalmente.